# Which class in android has a sleep() that there is no need to catch the exception ?

Tags: android

I remember there is a method can sleep the thread but no need to try..catch(),beacuse the method has already do it by himself.

so..who can tell me the name of that class ?   thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't do that. All you're saving is a try...catch and all you loose is readability and debuggability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One such class is [`SystemClock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep(long)).

Comment: Thanks, last night I have found that class, But also thank you :)